# R RStudio Resetting debug / function environment

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I am trying to stop R from displaying function code and environment information when I call a function.  This function is part of an assignment for Coursera R Programming that was provided by the instructor.  Here is the behavior:

R script:

```
makeVector <- function(x = numeric()) {
        m <- NULL
        set <- function(y) {
                x <<- y
                m <<- NULL
        }
        get <- function() x
        setmean <- function(mean) m <<- mean
        getmean <- function() m
        list(set = set, get = get,
             setmean = setmean,
             getmean = getmean)
}
```

I run the following in the console:

```
> x <- 1:10
> makeVector(x)
```

And get:

```
$set
function (y) 
{
    x <<- y
    m <<- NULL
}
<environment: 0x000000000967dd58>

$get
function () 
x
<environment: 0x000000000967dd58>

$setmean
function (mean) 
m <<- mean
<environment: 0x000000000967dd58>

$getmean
function () 
m
<environment: 0x000000000967dd58>
```

It appears RStudio is returning function code and environment information rather than executing the function.  Previously I ran debug(ls) and undebug(ls) as part of a quiz - it is my hunch that the debug() command has something to do with the behavior.

To fix the problem, I have already tried:

- deleting the RStudio-Desktop folder that contains RStudio settings. 
  This reverted my  appearance and global options to default, but the
  function calling behavior still happens.
- uninstalling and reinstalling both R and RStudio.  The behavior still happens as
  above.

**Does anyone know why RStudio is displaying function code and environment rather than executing the function?**

I really appreciate the help! Thanks!

Comment: Why would it execute the functions if you never actually call them?

Comment: To clarify - your function as written makes a few different functions and then returns them to the user in a list.  They never get called so why are you confused that they never were executed?

Comment: Wow, thanks for shining a light on that Dason...I guess I didn't look at it closely enough to see that it returns the functions via list.  I was also confused by the <environment> part, and I was expecting it to use x and return it as output in some manner.  So Dason are you saying the output I'm getting is what you'd expect?  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes that output is exactly what I would expect.  Also just in general as a good rule of thumb... if something isn't behaving the way you expect it to you might want to consider that you don't understand the language as much as you thought you did instead of jumping to the conclusion that the installation is borked and trying to uninstall everything.

Comment: Why is m <- NULL necessary in the first function?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, this has nothing to do with Rstudio: Rstudio is just an IDE, it would be very strange if it somehow managed to mess with your code, wouldn't it? The behaviour you see is completely fine and does exactly what it should. If you are familiar with OOP, what you get is an "object" with several methods. Here's a small demo that shows the intended usage:

```
x <- 1:10
xx <- makeVector(x)
xx$get()
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
xx$getmean()
#NULL
xx$setmean(mean(x))
xx$getmean()
#[1] 5.5
xx$setmean("Hi, I am a mean")
xx$getmean()
#[1] "Hi, I am a mean"
```