# Setting an object to itself

Tags: r

I am new to R and have a question on the function posted here: [R RStudio Resetting debug / function environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327741/r-rstudio-resetting-debug-function-environment). Why are the objects set to themselves (e.g. "getmean = getmean" etc.)? Couldn't it simply be written as follows: `list(set, get, setmean, getmean)`

Comment: I think the left term is the parameter name, the right term is the function name. In this case, they are equal, but it's not always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that

```
aa <- list(set, get, setmean, getmean)
```

is an unnamed list and

```
bb <- list(set=set, get=get, setmean=setmean, getmean=getmean)
```

is a named list. Compare `names(aa)` and `names(bb)`.

And that `=` is not assignment. It's really just giving a label to a list item. It's one of the reasons R programmers try to only use `<-` for assignment and leave `=` with this special meaning. You could have easily also done

```
cc <- list(apple=set, banana=get, ornage=setmean, grape=getmean)
cc$apple()
```

It doesn't have to be the exact same name.

Answer (score 0):

Because `list(set, get, setmean, getmean)` won't tag the list elements with the correct names. Here's an example of the difference between tagged and untagged lists:

```
> list(1, 2, 3)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

> list(foo=1, bar=2, baz=3)
$foo
[1] 1

$bar
[1] 2

$baz
[1] 3
```

Note that in the context of argument lists, `=` is used to supply named arguments, it does not do any assignments (unlike `<-`). Thus `list(foo=1, bar=2, baz=3)` is *very* different from `list(foo<-1, bar<-2, baz<-3)`.

Comment: Great, makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered, but you could also do this to achieve the same result.

```
> object <- c('set', 'get', 'setmean', 'getmean')
> setNames(object = as.list(object), nm = object)
# $set
# [1] "set"
# 
# $get
# [1] "get"
# 
# $setmean
# [1] "setmean"
# 
# $getmean
# [1] "getmean"
```

The quotations are dependent on what these values actually are.
And you can set different names with like this

```
> setNames(as.list(object), letters[1:4])
# $a
# [1] "set"
#
# $b
# [1] "get"
#
# $c
# [1] "setmean"
#
# $d
# [1] "getmean"
```

`setNames` comes in handy when working with `lapply`.